# Can't figure out regex match for list

Tags: python, regex

I'm not sure where to begin figuring out how to pull **just** the team names out of the small snippet of list below.  There seems to be so much variation.  Obviously, there is a single space preceding all teams names.  But they are not fixed length names and some have hyphens, apostrophes, and spaces inside of the team name themselves.  There is always at least one space after the last word of the team and before either the single "A" or a double "AA" letters at the end.

```
&nbsp  1  Clemson              A  =
&nbsp  5  Ohio State           A  =
&nbsp155  Tennessee-Martin     AA =
&nbsp152  Louisiana-Monroe     A  =
&nbsp104  Hawai'i              A  =
&nbsp193  VMI                  AA =
&nbsp202  Stephen F. Austin    AA =
```

Any Regex guys want to take a crack at this?

Comment: Is this getting scraped off of a website or is this a snippet of a text file? What's the original format?

Comment: @dizzyf It's scrapped off of https://www.usatoday.com/sports/ncaaf/sagarin/.  The page is a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's relatively easy:

```
import re

raw = """
&nbsp  1  Clemson              A  =
&nbsp  5  Ohio State           A  =
&nbsp155  Tennessee-Martin     AA =
&nbsp152  Louisiana-Monroe     A  =
&nbsp104  Hawai'i              A  =
&nbsp193  VMI                  AA =
&nbsp202  Stephen F. Austin    AA =
"""

teams = re.findall(r"&nbsp\s*\d+\s+(.*?)\s+A+\s+=", raw)

for team in teams:
    print(team)

# Clemson
# Ohio State
# Tennessee-Martin
# Louisiana-Monroe
# Hawai'i
# VMI
# Stephen F. Austin
```

Comment: This worked like a charm.  Now I need to go through what in the heck you did there to figure it out on my own...

Comment: Read @Nishanth Matha 's answer, he explains it quite well

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this? No regex required.

`lines` is a list of strings, where each string is a line from your data.

```
for line in lines:
    splits = line.split(" ")
    teamName = splits[1]
    if hasNumbers(teamName):
        teamName = splits[2]

    print(teamName)


def hasNumbers(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following regex:

```
\d\s+(.*?)\s+=

    - \d match digit
    - \s+ followed by one or more space
    - (.*) anything
    - \s+ followed by one or more spaces
    - = followed by  `=`
```

The captured group will give you team name

[*Regex Demo*](https://regex101.com/r/ItsqLl/2)

**Edit** if A/AA isn't part of team name do:

```
\d\s+(.*?)\s+[A]+\s+=
```

[*Updated Regex*](https://regex101.com/r/ItsqLl/4)

Comment: This will also capture A/AA at the end plus the whitespace, not just the team name.

Comment: @zwer I was under the impression that A/AA is part of team name. refer to edit if that's not the case

Comment: @NishanthMatha No, the A/AA was not part of the team name.  Your updated Regex seems to work now.  I just need to go though it to understand it.  I've got near zero working experience using Regex so its like a new language to me.